# Loading Jquery tab UI dynamically in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery-ui tabs plugin .

The trouble I am having is I load the tabs on a row click(table in html) and thus the tabs length can be dynamic on every row user clicks and also I built the tabs in HTML using angular directives

This is how I am create the tabs in angular

```
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <div id='tabs'>
                        <ul >
                            <li  ng-repeat="row in tabs.row">
                              <a href="#tabs-{{$index +2}}">{{row.Tab}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div   ng-repeat="row in tabs.row" id="tabs-{{$index + 2}}">
                           {{row.Tab}}
                       </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

Also I am a modal window , the trouble is the $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); function doesn't sync with ng-repeat  I wait it some time when my model is loaded and then call it ,like so

jsonData (In XML form for simplicity) :

```
<data>
        <row>
            <Tab>General</Tab>
        </row>
        <row>
            <Tab>Locations</Tab>
        </row>
        <row>
            <Tab>Treatment</Tab>
        </row>
        <row>
            <Tab>Training</Tab>
        </row>
        <row>
            <Tab>Facilities</Tab>
        </row>
        <row>
            <Tab>Equipment</Tab>
        </row>
        <row>
            <Tab>Physicians</Tab>
        </row>
        <row>
            <Tab>People</Tab>
        </row>
    </data>
```

Saving data:

```
$scope.tabs=jsonData;//save to model


     r =setTimeout(initTabs,500); //give some time to modal to save data  

         function initTabs(){
             $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
             console.log('timerCalled');
             r=clearTimeout();
          }
```

Now this works for the firs time , but any subsequent clicks to reset the tab results in the tabs having only one tab and are obscure .

Is there a way I can do this , I am thinking of someone resetting the classes added by #id.tabs() functionality but looking for a easier way .

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code called by $("#tabs2").tabs();
Currently I do not see any code which either initializes or modifies the tabs.row collection.

Comment: the code called by $(#tab).tabs is in the jquery-ui plugin for tabs it basically take the HTML and adds a bunch of css classes to it 

I have added how jsonData  is

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I can revert changes done by `#selector.tabs()` by using `#selector.destroy()`

Only catch is I have find a way if I have used #selector.tabs or not ,one way is:

```
if(selector.data("ui-tabs"))
```

Here is my re initialization code again :

```
                   function initTabs(){
                        if ($( "#tabs2" ).data("ui-tabs")) {
                            $( "#tabs2" ).tabs( "destroy" );
                        }
                        $( "#tabs2" ).tabs();
                        console.log('timer');
                        r=clearTimeout();
                    }
```